# Nextjs Component BG image

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js

How to add background image from index.js to a component in next.js

I tried,
From index.js

```js
<Card
  username="Name 1"
  bacimg={images.BaseCard}
  userimage={images.Avatar}
/>
```

This userimage is not assingning to the Component

```js
<div className="cards" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${bacimg})` }}>
```

on Card.jsx

Next.js answers to solve

Comment: What is being rendered as the inline style in your <div class="cards" style="" />? If you console.log(bacimg) in your Card component do you get the right address?  If so, can you have a look at your Network tab if your request to the url status is 200?